# How to add an array item to a document Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add (or create if first) an array of map like this in my document:

```
videos
 - 0
  - url : myurl
 - 1
  - url : another one
```

by console I can do this, by I don't know how to do in code. This is my current set method:

```dart
await databaseReference.collection("${mycol}").doc("${mydoc}")
        .set({
          'url': url,
        });
```

and this adds a simple string to database. How Could I do this add an item in that structure I mentioned early?

Update

And what if I have this :

```
videos
 - 0
  - url : myurl
  - name : myname
 - 1
  - url : another one
  - name : myname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add array by:-

```
List<Map> videos=[
    {
      'url':'url',
      'name':'Harry',
    },
    {
      'url':'url',
      'name':'John',
    }
  ];
    await databaseReference.collection("${mycol}").doc("${mydoc}")
            .set({
              'url': FieldValue.arrayUnion([videos]),
            });
```

Now, if you have added 3 elements and in future wanna add 4th one then:-

```
List<Map> new=[
{
'url':'url for 4th video',
'name':'4th person name',
},
];
await databaseReference.collection("${mycol}").doc("${mydoc}")
                .update({
                  'url': FieldValue.arrayUnion([videos]),
                });
```

The purpose of FielValue.arrayUnion is that it automatically adds the new data to the firebase i.e. now you will have 4 elements in the array (3 previously added and 1 recently added).

Comment: updated i hope it helps and if yes I request you to accept it as answer

Comment: But in this case I set there the content.. Can I 'merge' it? For example if there are 3 items, I want to add the fourth.. Did you understand me?

Comment: wait updating the answer.

Comment: Isn't automatic to check if there are elements (if yes update, if not set) ?

Comment: yes its automatic FieldValue.arrayUnion will append new element to list if not present then will create the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228314/discussion-between-armstrong-and-deepak-lohmod).

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection_name").doc(idItem).update({"filed_name":FieldValue.arrayUnion(nameList)});

In this case it would be:
await databaseReference.collection("${mycol}").doc("${mydoc}")
                .update({
                  'url': FieldValue.arrayUnion(videos),
                });

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a similar way to what you are doing right there. For example:

```
await _firestore.collection(mycol).document(mydoc)
  .setData({
    'videos': arrayOfUrls,
    // OR
    'videos': mapOfUrls
  });
```

Firebase supports arrays and maps out of the box!